# Abbreviating FAQ or not

Tags: wording, faq

Is there any data on how widely the *FAQ* abbreviation is understood by users, especially those who are older, compared to the full form *Frequently Asked Questions*? I'm designing a web app that will primarily have customers in the UK and Europe, and I'm wondering whether I can afford to take advantage of the shorter space taken up by the *FAQs* label or whether it will confuse some users.

Comment: How old are your users? How much do they browse the web?

Comment: For many years, I myself didn't know what FAQ stands for, but knew what the FAQ page contains :-]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the concept of FAQ dates back to Plato, and throughout history we can find examples of these. The specific word "FAQ" was originally from NASA to help save time and space due to the technical limitations at the time.

That said, it seems that FAQ is found almost everywhere. I even had a pamphlet from my kids holiday event that had a FAQ section on the back.

Depending on the type of project you are working on, you might have some room to change the text a bit, such as "Questions?", "Learn More", etc. (These are just examples i've come across.)

For more professional projects it's safe to say FAQ is a common abbreviation that is understood by the majority.